# How to add php data into highchart js file in php

Tags: php, mysql, highcharts

my code:

```
series: [{
            name: 'Brands',
            colorByPoint: true,
            <?php
            $models="SELECT * FROM purchase_info GROUP BY model_name";
            $models_querry=mysql_query($models);
            while($models_data=mysql_fetch_assoc($models_querry))
            {
            $model_name[]=$models_data['model_name'];
            }
            ?>
            data: [{
                name: ['<?php echo join($model_name, ',') ?>'],
                y: 56.33,
                drilldown: 'Hero Honda'
            }]
        }],
```

In my project i'm using high charts, in that how can i add php data into that, i just collect all data and saved into one variable named as `$model_name[]`, after that i pass the array value into data, but in that it will not spitted, all data's are echoed into single one.

[image]

Comment: The solution that @sneha provided is a good one. What I want to share with you is that you were setting your PHP data to the `name` attribute of your data, when it should go into the `y` attribute. `name` is simply the name of that series, and should only have one value. `y` in this case would be an array of your values.

Comment: can u sent the solution

Comment: Sorry, I just looked over your screenshot again and realized I misspoke. I meant that your PHP data should be **SPLIT** between the `name` and `data` fields so that it would be like: `{ name: 'Activa 3G', data: 40 }, { name: 'CB Hornet 16GR', data: 35 }, ... ` Again, the answer @sneha gave you is a really good one that should solve your issue.

Comment: ok ok i will try, but in that ajax is used

Comment: please see the link http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/data-from-a-database

Comment: i aslo use same method but it not working

Comment: What does your data output look like? Can you give me an `echo` of what's being returned? Seeing how that's formatted may help figure things out.

Comment: name: ['<?php echo join($model_name, ',') ?>'],

Comment: the entire data will showed in single line

Comment: OK, I meant what does the **data** that's returned from that 'echo' look like? I want to know what you're returning from your call.

Comment: <?php
        $models="SELECT * FROM purchase_info GROUP BY model_name";
        $models_querry=mysql_query($models);
        while($models_data=mysql_fetch_array($models_querry))
        {
        $model_name[]=$models_data['model_name'];
        }
        ?>

Comment: I'm sorry for the miscommunication. I would like to see what's returned from your query, not the query itself, and not the PHP code. The data: name, number, whatever you're trying to add to the chart series.

Comment: Could you paste your output final JSON ?

Answer (score 2):

*Use ajax for that..see the script code*

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'ajax.php',             
                    success: function(data) {
                        a = jQuery.parseJSON(data); 
                        i=0;
                        $.each( a.total_potential_score, function( key, val ) {
                           data1[i] = parseFloat(val);
                            i++;
                        });
                        rasterize_function(data1);
                      }
                });
```

*Ajax file look like this*

```
$a[0] = "1";
$a[1] = "2";
$a1['total_potential_score'][0] = "1";
$a1['department_name'][0] = "aaaaa";
$a1['total_potential_score'][1] = "3";
$a1['department_name'][1] = "bbbbb";
echo json_encode($a1);
```

*function for the highchart displayed here*

```
function rasterize_function(data1)  {
       var seriesArray = [];
       $.each( data1, function( key, val ) {
            seriesArray.push({
            name: "aaaa",
            data: [val],
            animation: false,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                rotation: -90,
                color: '#FFFFFF',
                align: 'right',
                x: 4,
                y: 10,
                style: {
                    fontSize: '13px',
                    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                }
            }

        });
    });
       $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'column',
                width: 700,
                height: 400,
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            title: {
                text: 'sector',
                align: 'left'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: ''
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['College, Personal Development and Career Scores'],
             },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Potential Score'
                }
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'horizontal',
                backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                x: 10,
                y: 7,
                floating: false,
                shadow: true
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return ''+
                        this.x +': '+ this.y +' points';
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    animation: false,
                    pointPadding: 0.2,
                    borderWidth: 0
                }
            },
            series:seriesArray  

        }); 
       }
```